# Bad state: Tried to read a provider that threw during the creation of its value. The exception occurred during the creation of type HomeBloc

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I added multiple blocs in my main file and use 1 bloc for every single screen, but when i go to next screen and come back to previous screen then again try to trigger event it gives error of bad state of second bloc.

main class

```
void main() {
  runApp(MultiBlocProvider(
      providers:[
        BlocProvider<LoginBloc>(
          create:(_) => LoginBloc(),
        ),
        BlocProvider<HomeBloc>(
            create: (_) => HomeBloc()
        ),
        BlocProvider<UnitBloc>(
            create: (_) => UnitBloc()
        ),
      ],
      child: MyApp()
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Watchman',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: MyColors.primaryTheme,
          bottomSheetTheme: BottomSheetThemeData(backgroundColor: Colors.transparent)
          // scaffoldBackgroundColor: MyColors.colorBGBrown
      ),
      home:  LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

login screen

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  LoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {

  final userController = TextEditingController();
  final pswdController = TextEditingController();

  String userName = '';
  String password = '';

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    userController.dispose();
    pswdController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => LoginBloc(),
      child: BlocListener<LoginBloc, LoginState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state is LoginSuccessState) {
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
            );
          } else if (state is LoginErrorState) {
            showInSnackBar(context, state.error);
          }
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Login'),

          ),
          body: BlocBuilder<LoginBloc, LoginState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              if (state is LoginLoadingState) {
                return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator()
                );
              } else {
                return Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.asset(
                      'Assets/iclogo.png',
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 40),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
                      child: TextFormFieldWidget(
                        labelText: 'UserName',
                        controller: userController,

                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
                      child: TextFormFieldWidget(
                        labelText: 'Password',
                        isPassword: true,
                        controller: pswdController,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
                      child: ElevatedButtonWidget(
                        onPressed: () {
                          userName = userController.text;
                          password = pswdController.text;


                          context.read<LoginBloc>().add(
                              LoginEventSubmit(
                                  username: userName,
                                  password: password)
                          );
                        },
                        text: 'Login',
                        bgColor: MyColors.colorPrimary,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void showInSnackBar(BuildContext context, String value) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text(value),
        // duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

login_bloc

```
class LoginBloc extends Bloc<LoginEvent, LoginState> {
  LoginBloc() : super(LoginInitial()) {
    on<LoginEvent>((event, emit) async {
      // TODO: implement event handler

      if(event is LoginEventSubmit){
        if(event.username.isEmpty || event.password.isEmpty){
          emit(LoginErrorState("Please Enter all Fields"));
        }else{
          emit(LoginLoadingState());
          try{
            print(event.username +".."+ event.password);
            final LoginModel user = await login(event.username ,event.password);
            if(user.result=="200"){
              emit(LoginSuccessState(user));
            }else {
              emit(LoginErrorState("UserName or Password is wrong"));
            }
          }catch (e){

              print("error..."+e.toString());

            emit(LoginErrorState("Login Failed"));
          }
        }
      }

    });
  }

  Future<LoginModel> login(String username, String pwd) async {
    final Dio _dio = Dio();


    final queryParameters = {
      'username': username,
      'pswd':pwd,
    };


    final response = await _dio.post(AppConstants.login,queryParameters: queryParameters);

      final jsonResponse =response.data;
      print(jsonResponse.toString());
      return LoginModel.fromJson(jsonResponse);

  }

}
```

home screen

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  // Initial Selected Value
   @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
     super.initState();
  }

  Development _selected = Development(
      dEVNAME: "Select Building",
      dEVCODE: "0"
  );

  // List of items in our dropdown menu
  List<Development>? devList ;



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<HomeBloc>(
      create: (context) => BlocProvider.of<HomeBloc>(context)..add(GetDevEvent()),
      child: BlocListener<HomeBloc, HomeState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          // TODO: implement listener

          if(state is HomeInitial){

          }else if (state is HomeErrorState){
            showInSnackBar(context, state.error);
          }else if(state is HomeLoadedState){

            // devList?.addAll(state.devList);
            devList= state.devList;
            devList?.add(_selected);
          }else if(state is HomeSelectedState){


              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UnitsPage(
                    devCode: state.devCode,
                    devName: state.devName,
                  )

                  )
              );

          }
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text("Home"),
          ),
          body: BlocBuilder<HomeBloc, HomeState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              if (state is HomeLoadingState) {

                return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator()
                );
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 15),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(color: MyColors.colorBlack),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                          ),
                          child: DropdownButton<Development>(
                            // Initial Value
                            value: _selected,
                            isExpanded: true,
                            // Down Arrow Icon
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                            iconSize: 25,

                            // Array list of items
                            items: devList?.map<DropdownMenuItem<Development>>((Development value) {
                              return DropdownMenuItem<Development>(
                                value: value,
                                child: Text(value.dEVNAME!),
                              );
                            }).toList(),
                            // After selecting the desired option,it will
                            // change button value to selected value
                            onChanged: (newVal) => setState(() => _selected = newVal!),
                          )
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: double.infinity,
                          padding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
                          child: ElevatedButtonWidget(
                            onPressed: () {

                              if(_selected.dEVCODE!="0"){
                                BlocProvider.of<HomeBloc>(context).add(
                                    DevSelectEvent(
                                      devCode:_selected.dEVCODE,
                                      devName: _selected.dEVNAME,
                                    )
                                );
                              }else{
                                String msg = "please "+_selected.dEVNAME!;
                                showInSnackBar(context, msg);
                              }


                            },
                            text: 'Search',
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void showInSnackBar(BuildContext context, String value) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text(value),
        // duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

home bloc

```
class HomeBloc extends Bloc<HomeEvent, HomeState> {
  HomeBloc() : super(HomeInitial()) {
    on<HomeEvent>((event, emit) async {
      // TODO: implement event handler



      if(event is GetDevEvent){

          emit(HomeLoadingState());
          try{

           DevData devList = await getData();


           if(devList.result =="1"){
             emit(HomeLoadedState(devList.development));
             print("data.."+ devList.toString());
           }else{
             emit(HomeErrorState("No data Found"));
           }


          }catch (e){

            print("error..."+e.toString());

            emit(HomeErrorState("Failed"));
          }
        }

      if(event is DevSelectEvent){
        emit(HomeLoadingState());
        emit(HomeSelectedState(event.devName!,event.devCode!));
      }

    });
  }

   Future<DevData> getData() async {
    final Dio _dio = Dio();

    final response = await _dio.post(AppConstants.getDevs);

    final jsonResponse =response.data;
    print(jsonResponse.toString());
    return DevData.fromJson(jsonResponse);

  }

}
```

Error log:

```
Bad state: Tried to read a provider that threw during the creation of its value.
The exception occurred during the creation of type HomeBloc.

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY PROVIDER ╞═══════════════════════════════
The following StateError was thrown:
Bad state: Cannot add new events after calling close

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#1      Bloc.add (package:bloc/src/bloc.dart:84:24)
#2      _HomePageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:watchman/Home/HomePage.dart:39:64)
#3      _CreateInheritedProviderState.value (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:729:36)
#4      _InheritedProviderScopeElement.value (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:583:33)
#5      Provider.of (package:provider/src/provider.dart:303:37)
#6      ReadContext.read (package:provider/src/provider.dart:656:21)
#7      _BlocListenerBaseState.initState (package:flutter_bloc/src/bloc_listener.dart:147:36)
#8      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4942:57)
#9      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4781:5)
#10     SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:222:11)
#11     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:16)
#12     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#13     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#14     _InheritedProviderScopeElement.performRebuild (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:495:11)
#15     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#16     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4787:5)
#17     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4781:5)
#18     _InheritedProviderScopeElement.mount (package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:395:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#25     SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:222:11)
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#32     SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount (package:nested/nested.dart:222:11)
...     Normal element mounting (283 frames)
#315    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:16)
#316    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6350:36)
#317    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
#318    RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5883:32)
#319    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6375:17)
#320    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#321    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#322    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
```

Comment: i try create: context.read<HomeBloc>().add(GetDevEvent()), but it gives this error, This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this issue by adding my first event inside initstate(), instead of BlocProvder.

```
 late HomeBloc bloc;

  // Initial Selected Value
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    bloc = HomeBloc();
    bloc.add(GetDevEvent());
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    bloc.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
```